# Pandas Dataframe drop duplicates in a column of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to remove duplicates in columns `a` and `c`.

```
        a      b    c
0  [1, 0]      1    ab
1  [0, 0]      2    bc
2  [1, 0]      3    ab
```

Resultant Output:

```
        a      b    c
0  [1, 0]      1    ab
1  [0, 0]      2    bc
```

What i have tried:
With out `a` column being list. `df.drop_duplicates(['a','c'])` works.

Without `c` column being str. `pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df), columns=df.columns)` works for droping duplicate lists.

How to proceed if one the columns is a list and other string.

Comment: You would be *much* better off storing `a` in multiple columns.  Pandas doesn't deal with lists well.

Comment: Okay, Then i'll convert them to string and drop the duplicates

Comment: Why not convert it to two columns of integers?

Comment: Are the lists in column `a` all of the same length and is the length always 2?

Answer (score 5):

**Method 1**

Lists are not hashable in pandas but you can use tuple.

`df['d']  = df['a'].apply(lambda x : tuple(x) if type(x) is list else x)`

```
          a  b   c       d
0    [1, 0]  1  ab  (1, 0)
1    [0, 0]  2  bc  (0, 0)
2    [1, 0]  3  ab  (1, 0)
```

then

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['c', 'd'])
```

result :

```
         a  b   c       d
0    [1, 0]  1  ab  (1, 0)
1    [0, 0]  2  bc  (0, 0)
```

**Method 2**

You can convert columns containing lists to str.

```
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(str)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['a', 'c'])
```

Output

```
    a      b    c
0  [1, 0]      1    ab
1  [0, 0]      2    bc
```